# Does parallel download on a google cloud VM makes sense?

Tags: parallel-processing, download, google-cloud-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud VM and I have multiple satellite data to download. For that, I use an R package that does the exchange. Can I somehow take advantage of Google Cloud features to download these files faster, maybe in parallel?

Comment: Only if you have two network wires.

Comment: I'm running the analysis on the Google cloud VM.

Comment: No. Async is made for that. No need to use multiple cores. Few async connections will certainly be enough. This is true for most network download.

Comment: I see, I thought I could use some google cloud feature that would allow me multiple connections or something like that.